# XCode In Call Status bar changing the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I had created a Viewcontroller in XCode, everything is working fine. When a phone call comes, the in Call Status bar is pushing the button in the bottom of the view "DOWN" due to that I am unable to click the button during the phone call.

I would like to know how to keep the buttons in the bottom, the same position even when the phone call comes. I tried several methods nothing worked for me.

```
- (void)statusBarFrameWillChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSValue* rectValue = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];
    CGRect newFrame;
    [rectValue getValue:&newFrame];
    CGRect fixedFrame = bottomBar.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = fixedFrame.origin.y - newFrame.size.height; //Keep the Y position as it is
    bottomBar.frame = fixedFrame;
    NSLog(@"statusBarFrameWillChange: newSize %f, %f, %f", fixedFrame.origin.y, newFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
}

- (void)statusBarFrameChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSValue* rectValue = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];
    CGRect oldFrame;
    [rectValue getValue:&oldFrame];
    CGRect fixedFrame = bottomBar.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = fixedFrame.origin.y + oldFrame.size.height;
    bottomBar.frame = fixedFrame;
    NSLog(@"statusBarFrameChanged: oldSize %f, %f, %f", fixedFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using autolayout, make sure you set a `Bottom Space` constraint:

[image]